# javascript quiz ,appropriate message should be displayed and submit button issue

Tags: javascript

my task consists of writing javascript code for a quiz. every piece of code is good but  the main problem is that i should display another message at the end of the quiz saying that if i got all questions correct. a congratulation message should be displayed. (for ex. you got 3 of 3 questions correct, congratulations.)also, we cannot proceed to the next page if the current question hasn't been answered.the submit button should be disabled. should i use an alert box??

```js
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B" ],
 [ "What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C" ],
 [ "What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A" ],
 [ "What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C" ]
];
function _(x){
 return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
 test = _("test");
 if(pos >= questions.length){
  test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
  _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
  pos = 0;
  correct = 0;
  return false;
 }
 _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
 question = questions[pos][0];
 chA = questions[pos][1];
 chB = questions[pos][2];
 chC = questions[pos][3];
 test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
 test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
 test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
 test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
 test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
 choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
 for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
  if(choices[i].checked){
   choice = choices[i].value;
  }
 }
 if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
  correct++;
 }
 pos++;
 renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

```html
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
```

```js
var pos = 0, test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B" ],
 [ "What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C" ],
 [ "What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A" ],
 [ "What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C" ]
];
function _(x){
 return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
 test = _("test");
 if(pos >= questions.length){
  test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
  _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
  pos = 0;
  correct = 0;
  return false;
 }
 _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
 question = questions[pos][0];
 chA = questions[pos][1];
 chB = questions[pos][2];
 chC = questions[pos][3];
 test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
 test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
 test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
 test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
 test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
 choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
 for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
  if(choices[i].checked){
   choice = choices[i].value;
  }
 }
 if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
  correct++;
 }
 pos++;
 renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
```

```html
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Why did you uncheck my answer? Didn't work for you? Are you missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change this line:

```
test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
```

for this one:

```
test.innerHTML = (correct == questions.length ? "CONGRATULATIONS!!! " : "") + "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
if(pos >= questions.length){
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        //shows message
        alert("You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct");

        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
```